# Load page at specific path in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function which runs on page-load and reads the URL, setting the data to an object.

To test this I need to set the location at the start of the test.

If I try using `window.location.assign`, `window.location.replace` or `window.location.href` I get this error:

```sh
Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)
```

I've tried all of the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090231/how-to-fix-error-not-implemented-navigation-except-hash-changes) post, but none of them works.

---

If I try to reassign `window.location.assign`:

```
test('Correct load-state', () => {
  window.location.assign = jest.fn()
  window.location.assign('/about')
})
```

I get:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'assign' of object '[object Location]'
```

---

If I try `Object.defineProperty`:

```
test('Correct load-state', () => {
  const mockResponse = jest.fn()
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: {
      href: window.location.href,
      assign: mockResponse
    },
    writable: true
  })
  window.location.assign('/about')

  console.log(mockResponse.mock) // assign *is* called with '/about'
  console.log(href) // http://localhost/
})
```

`assign` is called but nothing updates to match `/about`.

---

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you show the code you want to test?

Comment: It's too long and irrelevant. It basically just parses the url and formats an object from it

Comment: If you think it might be useful, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/Daniel-Knights/svelte-dk-router/blob/main/src/router/logic/load.ts)