# Warning when clicking a link in Jest and React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a React component that should download a file and display an alert when a link is clicked. I'm using Jest and React-testing-library for my tests, but I'm running into an error message.

Here's the code for my test:

```
test('clicking the link should download a file and display an alert', async () => {
  const { getByRole } = render(<MyComponent />);
  const link = getByRole('link');

  await fireEvent.click(link);

  expect(within(screen.getByRole('alert')).getByText(/File downloaded/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

When I run this test, I get the following error message:

```
Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)
```

The test works but I would like to get rid of the warning message.

I tried every solution proposed in this post: [How to fix Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090231/how-to-fix-error-not-implemented-navigation-except-hash-changes)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Show the code of the `MyComponent` component